# Raphael JS 2 Hover event

Tags: raphael

Hi I'm currently experimenting with Raphael JS 2 and have produced a nice circle of paths but after much searching cannot figure out how to implement a hover event on these paths to change the color...

http://jsfiddle.net/goosefat/HYmd2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This fiddle changes a bit the way you set the hover functions. If that's not what you want, please explain.

http://jsfiddle.net/vzkxC/1/

Raphael's documentation http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover says you can pass the context of the hoverIn and hoverOut functions as third and fourth parameters (in my example they're both `cItem`). These are the values of the `this` inside the callbacks.

Of course, you could move the `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` functions to an appropriate scope (out of the `for` loop)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Marcelo's example is more readabe/maintainable, use his.

You need a closure to achieve it:

```
(function (cItem) {
  cItem.hover(function(){
    cItem.attr({"stroke": "#E3E3E3"});
  },
  function(){
    cItem.attr({"stroke": "#000"});
});    
})(cItem)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxDap/

Answer (score 3):

Another nice method for you to handle **this kind of problems**, code here:

(Event handler defined like this)

```
var hoverIn = function (item) {
    return function (event) {
        self.hoverFlag = true;
        self.hintElementObj = {};
        self._drawHint(paper, event, item);
    };
};
```

(Event handler called like this）

```
paper.rect(x, y, item.rectWidth, item.rectHeight, round).attr({
    fill: fill,
    "stroke-width": 0
}).hover(hoverIn(item), hoverOut(item));
```

In fact, this is a JS trick that you could use in many situations. With it you could do many more interesting things.